# Kendo AutoComplete with MVVM | Not setting bound object

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Telerik's `Kendo UI` and their `autocomplete` widget in conjunction with their `MVVM` framework, and am having a bit of a hard time with getting a box to set the retrieved (and selected) object to the bound one on the view model. For example...

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
  Context: {}
});

$("#context").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    delay: 800,
    dataSource: {
        dataType: "json",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/search/data",
                data: function (data) {
                        return {
                        term: data.filter.filters[0].value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).data("kendoAutoComplete");
```

Then I use the following HTML;

```
<input data-val="true"
       id="context"
       name="context"
       placeholder="Context"
       type="text"
       data-bind="value: Context" />
```

This hits a controller action that returns the following;

```
[
  {
    Id: "items/1",
    Name: "Item 1",
    Label: "Item 1 Label"
  },
  {
    Id: "items/2",
    Name: "Item 2",
    Label: "Item 2 Label"
  },
  {
    Id: "items/3",
    Name: "Item 3",
    Label: "Item 3 Label"
  }
]
```

However when I select the object after using the autocomplete to search for it, the `Context` property on my viewmodel remains `null`.

I can circumvent this by adding a specific `select` function.

```
select: function(e) {
    var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(e.item.index()).toJSON();
    // update the model
    viewModel.set('Context', dataItem);
}
```

but I would really rather just it work like it is supposed to; Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you define `viewModel` as an `Observable` object but you are not binding it to the `input`.

Try adding the binding as follow:

```
kendo.bind($("#context"), viewModel);
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/DYVLT/

Comment: Yes, I have that in the code; Sorry, I just assumed it was understood part of the behavior. There are other bindings in the page and they all bind correctly.

Comment: But does the JSFiddle that I imcluded in the answer work for you?

Comment: This still does not set the property to the actual selected item; Your example only gets the actual label of the text.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem I have is that I need the whole object; Not just the name.

Comment: Hey, I spent more time with your demo and I figured something out; If you remove the `dataValueField` and put in `valuePrimitive: false`, it correctly sets it to the entire JSON object! Demo is here : http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/7y56D/

Though I still have one more problem. When the widget first loads, it is showing as [Object object] in the text box. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: That's exactly what I've expected. Binding a JSON object to an HTML `input` field is pretty weird since it needs to convert the JSON into a string. What is exactly what you want to achieve?